# console output from the jenkins shows timeout and errors

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

Hello All,
        I am trying to integrate jenkins, git ,maven, corbetura for a java project.
        I have integrated and built a job in jenkins which shows following error

```
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/integration project/workspace git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/syedirfan7/test1.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/syedirfan7/test1.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/syedirfan7/test1.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision ad31beeb92f9cde2f43d8534c6043f350fbd1c02 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f ad31beeb92f9cde2f43d8534c6043f350fbd1c02
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[workspace] $ mvn clean package
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/integration project/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:240)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:212)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:815)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:381)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:388)
    at hudson.tasks.Maven.perform(Maven.java:331)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 15 more
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Recording test results
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run? 
For example, /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/integration project/workspace/business/impl/target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.in28minutes.example.layering.business.client.ClientBOMockitoTest.xml is 2 hr 11 min old

Finished: FAILURE
```

i pushed the repository from my system via git bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no timeouts in the log, but if you read the stacktrace, you'll see it says:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/integration project/workspace"): error=2, No such file or directory

So either Maven (i.e. the `mvn` command) is not installed, or it's not available on the PATH that Jenkins is using.

Comment: my project has 3.3 maven version and i already have a stable maven plugin of Maven Integration plugin(2.12.1)

Comment: Going through the Configuration i changed the **bold** Default  @christopher

Comment: Changing the maven version from **Default** to **maven** in the drop down helped me to solve this issue.